# Vue SSR from scratch - problem with loading server webpack bundle on client

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to build document generator service and my document templates are written in Vue because of flexibility etc.

**The context** (feel free to skip this to **The question** part)

1. Client writes his document template in Vue with use of my library written for this purpose
2. Client uploads this template to my server. After that this template is automatically built using webpack as commonjs module with transpiled vue component as default export.
   For reference - here is how on of the templates looks like:

```
{
    __name: "NajomnaZmluva",
    props: {
        "landlords": {
            "required": true
        },
        "tenants": {
            "required": true
        },
        "contractedProperty": {
            "required": true
        },
        "edit": { 
            "required": false,
            "default": false
        }
    },
    __file: "templates/reality_module/NajomnaZmluva.vue",
    setup: ƒsetup(__props, { expose: __expose }) { ... }
    ssrRender: ƒssrRender(_ctx, _push, _parent, _attrs, $props, $setup, $data, $options) { ... }
}
```

3. After successful build client can send calls to `/render` ep with props as a payload.
4. This EP returns rendered HTML string of the template.

This works well but doesn't quite fulfill my needs - I need to somehow edit this template on frontend so if something isn't right I can correct it or override it. For this I've added more robust functionality to my templater vue library that can be triggered by switching `edit` prop to `true` - this transforms my template into full fledged reactive document editor.

**The question**

How can I import my transpiled webpack bundle(served as a static asset on the server) on client from the server and extract from it default export - that is my Vue component that I can pass to this code:

```
  private hydrateDocument(
    component: TranspiledComponent,
    selector: string,
    tp: Record<string, any>
  ) {
    createApp({
      render() {
        return h(component, tp);
      },
    }).mount(selector);
  }
```

**What I've tried**

1. axios call - this returns only raw string. I've no clue what and if I can do something with it
2. `eval` - tried to pass the string to `eval` but (un)fortunately it resulted into errors...It was just an experiment and I would like not to use `eval`
3. Conversion of the string into a `Blob` - and after that into an `ObjectURL` that I've passed to `import` statement - browser denied it

I have no clue how can I load my transpiled component so I can hydrate it on the client side. How nuxt and other SSR fws handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you're aiming for, you need to dynamically load and execute the transpiled Vue component on the client-side. Here's a general approach you can take:

1. Server-Side: Serve your transpiled Vue component as a static asset from your server.
2. Client-Side: Fetch the transpiled Vue component using an HTTP request and once you have the component code on the client-side, you need to dynamically evaluate it.

Here's how you could approach the client-side code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'; 

async function fetchAndRenderComponent() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/path/to/transpiled/component');
        const componentCode = response.data; // Assuming the response contains the component code as a string

        // Dynamically evaluate the component code
        const componentModule = new Function('module', componentCode);
        const { default: TranspiledComponent } = componentModule({}); // Pass any required globals if necessary
        
        // Now you can use the TranspiledComponent
        const app = createApp({
            render() {
                return h(TranspiledComponent, {});
            },
        });

        app.mount('#app'); // Replace '#app' with your selector
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching or rendering component:', error);
    }
}

fetchAndRenderComponent();
```

Comment: This technically works but I struggle with the same challenges as with `eval` and I'm not sure if I want to resolve them as this approach is not the best practice. I'm going to find another solution and will update you whether I found one or not - if not I'm gonna stick with this solution.

Comment: It looks like I have no other choice as I need to execute this code on the client in order to import from it...I will try to secure the source of this code as much as possible.

Comment: I also searched for another solution but didn't find anything useful, hope this helps you, good luck.